# How do I rebuild MFC project in x64?

Tags: mfc, 64-bit

I have project in MFC that works fine in x32.

I used the configuration manager to change the project to x64, then I tried to rebuild the project.

the result was "unresolved external symbol" for many MFC function.

I guess that I miss something here in the Tools/Option toolbar with x64 platform but I don't know what.

P.S.

win32 console application works fine when I change the platfrom to x64

Comment: I've run into this with some apps that used MFC in a static library. Switching to using MFC in a DLL fixed it. No guarantee of course, but if you're using MFC in a static library, it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

For our apps, it was a matter of changing to x64 using the Configuration Manager in VS 2005, recompiling, and fixing a few things here and there as prompted by warnings.  It worked fine, although due to the size it took a while to get through everything.

In other words, what you did should have worked, assuming you did it properly.  You have provided no details on how you changed the project, or what functions are "unresolved external symbol", or any details of configuration.  I strongly suggest you post more details.

You also should make sure VS x64 is fully installed on your machine.  I've seen a few problems there.

Comment: one of the unresolved external symbol function is
static struct CRuntimeClass* _cdecd CFrameWndEx::GetThisClass

Comment: When I look up CFrameWndEx on MSDN, I see no GetThisClass.  There could be a problem with my searching, but are you sure this is a standard MFC function?

Comment: I reinstalled the VS 2008 and now it's work fine,
Thank for your professional guidance

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by David, you should check for full installation of VS x64. 
The unresolved references may be showing up due to some extra inputs to the linker given in project properties, may be due to some specific 32 bit lib file that you may have included.

Comment: I tried a simple dialog application witout any changing by me.
and still I got unresolved external symbo

Comment: Do you have the link for the full installation of VS 2008 x64?
(there are so many version in the msdn site)

Comment: Chcek this link and see if it helps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Also ensure that when you might have had installed Visual Studio, you should have had selected All Components instead of the default selection if you are not sure. I dont recollect whether default selection does include 64 bit or not. Otherwise, you may want to review the selected components and ensure that 64 bit support is included.

Comment: I reinstalled the VS 2008 and now it's work fine,
Thank for your professional guidance